# Is the Intellij IDEA code inspector always frowning? Is there a metric that will make him smile?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been trying to fix every inspection warning in my project - but under no circumstances have been able to make the inspector smile. Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: emojis are coming soon ✌⊂(✰‿✰)つ✌

Comment: I prefer to believe that that is his moustache and not his mouth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an indicator of a metric -- it is an icon to show what highlighting level you have selected.  Click on it, and you can use the slider to change the highlighting level.  The icon will change according to your choice.

Comment: All the icons are frowning.  The middle one is looking to the side, but still frowning.  The left one has his back turned towards you, but, since he is an inspector he is frowning nonetheless, as all inspectors do.